# Data for Tully-Fisher Relation

Tags: resource-recommendations, galaxy-rotation-curve

I have a derivation of the Tully-Fisher Relation and I'd like to test it against some real data.  Does anyone know of a catalog where I can find the maximum velocity ($V_{flat}$) and radius (of $V_{flat}$) of galaxies?

Answer (score 0):

Here (http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1512.04543) is a today archive link investigating the Baryon Tully Fisher relation.  The authors use (and reference) ~100 galaxies with $V_{flat}$ measured in the radio by HI.  Perhaps this will be good for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there's no radius information.  I'll try contacting the author to see if he'll post the data.  Stacy McGaugh is exceptionally good at posting the data he uses on line.